# Check whether a worker is self-hosted or an Azure-operated one

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

For our product it is necessary to know whether someone could has botched with a build in Azure Pipelines by accessing the worker machine.

So we want to know whether it has been an agent which is self-hosted by the user or which is one provided by Azure Pipelines. The latter is trustworthy, the former is not.

Does anybody know how to obtain this information ("self-hosted by user" or "provided by Azure Pipelines") via the build succeeded web hook or via the REST API?

Answer (score 1):

By directly clicking into a build record, you can see if the agent used is hosted or private.
[image]
You can also add a powershell task to the agent job of build pipeline and add the following script.

```
Write-Host agent id : $(agent.id) , agent name : $(agent.name)
```

Because agent.name and agent.id are environment variables, you can get them directly, and then output them in the power shell. By the name, you can judge whether the agent used is hosted or private.

[image]

Comment: Thank you, I should have said, that we need a programmatic way to do so. The PowerShell idea is not bad, but I'm scared that someone will give his/her agent the same name as a hosted one. Any ideas to overcome the problem?

Comment: The answer provided by Shayki Abramczyk can solve this problem perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

The web hook got the information like the "Builds - Get" Rest API that contains the Agent pool name and also a property `isHosted`:

```
queue: {
           "id": 10
           "name": "Hosted VS2017"
           "pool": {
                       "id": 4,
                       "name": "Hosted VS2017",
                       "isHosted": true
                   }
       }
```

So, if `isHosted` is `true` the worker machine is "Provided by Azure Pipelines" and if i's `false` the worker is "self-hosted by user".

You also can assuming that if the pool name contains the word "Hosted" it's Microsoft Hosted Agent because those pools can't be removed.

Comment: The queue only shows the initial build agent, not the ones of the jobs that have run. Is there a way to get this information (including the isHosted flag) for each worker that has run a job for a build?

Comment: Do you have build with a few jobs?

Comment: I'm a tool vendor, so I don't know how many jobs my users will have. At least one, and the one is not necessarily the agent specified in the queue.